# How to filter nested objects on a should query?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have my mappings as below and I am doing a bool should query on name and other properties as shown below but what I need is that I want to filter CustomerPrices by CustomerId on response. 
Each products have same CustomerIds so for eaxample;

```
product1 -CustomerPrice( CustomerId :1234 -Price:4) 
           CustomerPrice( CustomerId :567-Price:5)
            .
            .
 Product2 - CustomerPrice(CustomerId :1234 -Price:8)
            CustomerPrice(CustomerId :567-Price:10)
           .
           .
```

So according to that when I query Product1, response should have only customerPrice for customerId:1234

```
{
  "Product": {
    "properties": {
      "CustomerPrices": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "Price": {
            "store": true,
            "type": "float"
          },
          "CustomerId": {
            "type": "integer"
          }
        }
      },
      "Name": {
        "index": "not_analyzed",
        "store": true,
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried following query but this is not filtering nested objects. I guess it filters product objects as it makes sense because all products have customerId:1234

```
   "query":{
        "bool":{
          "should":[
            {
              "multi_match":{
                "type":"best_fields",
                "query":"product 1",
                "fields":[             
                  "Name^7"]
              }
            },
            {
              "multi_match":{
                "type":"best_fields",
                "query":"product 1",
                "operator":"and",
                "fields":[
                  "Code^10",           
                  "ShortDescription^6"]
              }
            },      
            {
              "nested":{
                "query":{
                  "term":{
                    "CustomerPrices.CustomerId":{
                      "value":1234
                    }
                  }
                },
                "path":"CustomerPrices"
              }
            }]
        }
      },
```

Answer (score 2):

I've spent some time on your question since it was interesting how this can be achieved and the only solution I found for now is relying on the *inner_hits* which gives the exact nested object the match was on. I've also deactivated the *_source* which isn't used anymore.

So given your mapping and having 2 products like:

```
PUT product/Product/product1
{
  "CustomerPrices": [
    {
      "CustomerId": 1234,
      "Price": 4
    },
    {
      "CustomerId": 567,
      "Price": 5
    }
  ],
  "Name": "John"
}

PUT product/Product/product2
{
  "CustomerPrices": [
    {
      "CustomerId": 1234,
      "Price": 8
    },
    {
      "CustomerId": 567,
      "Price": 10
    }
  ],
  "Name": "Bob"
}
```

When running the following query: (Used *must* just to see 1 result, works with *should* as well)

```
GET product/_search
{
  "_source": false,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { "match": { "Name": "Bob"}}
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "nested" : {
            "path" : "CustomerPrices",
            "score_mode" : "avg",
            "query" : {
              "bool" : {
                "should" : [
                  { "match" : {"CustomerPrices.CustomerId" : 1234}}
                ]
              }
            },
            "inner_hits": {}
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I was able to get the result where only "Price" from customer with id 1234 was present:

```
{
  "took": 5,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 0.2876821,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "product",
        "_type": "Product",
        "_id": "product2",
        "_score": 0.2876821,
        "inner_hits": {
          "CustomerPrices": {
            "hits": {
              "total": 1,
              "max_score": 1,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "product",
                  "_type": "Product",
                  "_id": "product2",
                  "_nested": {
                    "field": "CustomerPrices",
                    "offset": 0
                  },
                  "_score": 1,
                  "_source": {
                    "CustomerId": 1234,
                    "Price": 8
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Couldn't find an official way of returning partial results of the document by only having the matched nested object. Maybe something that we need to inform elasticsearch guys about to consider for some next releases. Hope it helps you.

Comment: thanks for your reply and try but i think that my query above returns also same results within the inner hits. I was looking for without using inner hits but obviously as you said that it is not possible. I asked on elasticserch forum one more time to see if possible. i will update here with their answer. thanks

Comment: You welcome, yes, would be interesting to see what they answer. If you will consider using the inner hits than you might modify your query by taking mine as an example. I've tested it with must/should and it gives the wanted result for both. Cheers.